# Angularfire cannot read property 'push' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to create a new object in the database for an assessment, right now its hardcoded to just try get it working but will be dynamic from view. I currently get an error Cannot read property 'push' of null, which leads me to believe the assessment object isn't being passed back correctly? Or is it something to do with firebase not already having an object waiting to receive it?

I've literally duplicated code I've used elsewhere which works so unsure as to what I'm doing wrong!

model

```
export class AssessmentItem {
  $key: string;
  first: string;
  second: string;
  third: string;
  education: number;
  employment: number;
  health: number;
  social: number;
  civic: number;
  housing: number;
}
```

service

```
  assessmentItems: FirebaseListObservable<AssessmentItem[]> = null;
  assessmentItem: FirebaseObjectObservable<AssessmentItem> = null;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              private  afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    // setting userId returned from auth state to the userId on the service, now we can query
    // currently logged in user, using the id. IMPORTANT
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) this.userId = user.uid
    })
  }

createAssessmentItem(assessmentItem: AssessmentItem) {
     this.assessmentItems.push(assessmentItem)
       .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
   }
```

ts file

```
   assessments: FirebaseListObservable<AssessmentItem[]>;

  assessment: AssessmentItem = new AssessmentItem;

  constructor(private visionService: VisionService,
              public auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.assessments = this.visionService.getAssessment();
  }
 test() {
    this.assessment.first = "test";
    this.assessment.second = "test";
    this.assessment.third = "test";
    this.assessment.education = 1;
    this.assessment.civic = 1;
    this.assessment.employment = 1;
    this.assessment.health = 1;
    this.assessment.housing = 1;
    this.assessment.social = 1;
    this.visionService.createAssessmentItem(this.assessment)
    console.log(this.assessment);
  }
```

the view how it will be used

```
<md-card-content>
    <p>List 3 things that they did that you think helped them become successful:</p>
    <md-input-container>
      <textarea mdInput
                placeholder="First"
                [(ngModel)]="assessment.first"
                (ngModelChange)="assessment.first"></textarea>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <textarea mdInput
                placeholder="Second"
                [value]="assessment.second"
                [ngModel]="assessment.second"
                (ngModelChange)="assessment.second"></textarea>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <textarea mdInput
                placeholder="Third"
                [value]="assessment.third"
                [ngModel]="assessment.third"
                (ngModelChange)="assessment.third">></textarea>
    </md-input-container>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>


<md-card class="result">
  <md-card-content>
    <p>Education</p>
    <md-slider
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [step]="step"
      [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
      [tick-interval]="tickInterval"
      [value]="0"
      [ngModel]="assessment.education"
      (ngModelChange)="assessment.education">
    </md-slider>
    <p>Employment</p>
    <md-slider
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [step]="step"
      [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
      [tick-interval]="tickInterval"
      [value]="0"
      [ngModel]="assessment.employment"
      (ngModelChange)="assessment.employment">
    </md-slider>
    <p>Health and Wellbeing</p>
    <md-slider
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [step]="step"
      [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
      [tick-interval]="tickInterval"
      [value]="step - 1"
      [ngModel]="assessment.health"
      (ngModelChange)="assessment.health">
    </md-slider>
    <p>Social Connections</p>
    <md-slider
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [step]="step"
      [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
      [tick-interval]="tickInterval"
      [value]="step - 1"
      [ngModel]="assessment.social"
      (ngModelChange)="assessment.social">
    </md-slider>
    <p>Civic Participation</p>
    <md-slider
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [step]="step"
      [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
      [tick-interval]="tickInterval"
      [value]="step - 1"
      [ngModel]="assessment.civic"
      (ngModelChange)="assessment.civic">
    </md-slider>
    <p>Housing and Living Skills</p>
    <md-slider
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [step]="step"
      [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
      [tick-interval]="tickInterval"
      [value]="step - 1"
      [ngModel]="assessment.housing"
      (ngModelChange)="assessment.housing">
    </md-slider>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
<button md-raised-button (click)="test()">test button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your service, you're not creating instances for `assessmentItems` and `assessmentItems`, so they're `null` - the value with which they've been initialized.

You need to call the `list` method of the injected `db` to create an instance for `assessmentItems`:

```ts
constructor(
  private db: AngularFireDatabase,
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

  this.assessmentItems = db.list('some/path/some/key');
}
```

You also need to create an instance for `assessmentItem`, but it's not clear for the snippet how (or where) you intend to use it.

Comment: awesome that makes sense, I'm intending to use it in a view attached to that ts file, i'll add it now. the only other question I really need help to understand is getting attributes from a single item e.g. the model here.